# How To Stop Displaying php extension after Redirect from www to non-www

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I wanted to hide the php extension so writed

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

I want to force redirect www to non www so i writed the htaccess code

```
RewriteBase /
#Force non-www:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It redirecting nicely www to non www version
But Not Perfectly As,
when i'm typing url **www.something.com** it is redirecting to **something.com** 
But when giving url **www.something.com/test** it is redirecting to **something.com/test.php**

and also when  i'm typing url **www.something.com/example?id=1** it is redirecting to **something.com/example.php?id=1**

How To do redirect like **www.something.com/test** to **something.com/test** and not to show php extension after redirect.

Answer (score 1):

If your *redirect* rule comes after your .php *rewrite* rule, then your problem is that the *rewritten* URL is getting redirected. I.e.:

1. First rule is hit, request is rewritten from `www.example.com/test` to `www.example.com/test.php`.
2. The second rule takes effect, redirecting to `example.com/test.php`.

Either move your redirect rule above the other rule, or *stop processing of further rules* by adding `[L]` after `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php`.

Comment: Its workd.. wrote the redirection rule and then wrote hiding php ext rule an got workd.